# How do I make the commands I enter bold in ZSH with oh-my-zsh?

Tags: formatting, zsh, ps1, bold

I have configured PS1 and made the entire prompt bold

.zshrc contains as follows

```
PS1="%{$fg_bold[yellow]%}%n@%m %{$fg[blue]%}%~ \$ %{$reset_color%}%{$fg_bold[white]%}"
preexec() { printf "\e[1m"; }
```

Whatever I type in after the prompt is appearing bold only when I load from the buffer.
For example, [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WI1QD.png) me typing `echo "this is text"` does not appear in bold.

I am on Ubuntu 18.04 and am trying to move to zsh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Zshell Line Editor (zle) lets you format the command buffer.

```
PS1='%F{yellow}B%n@%m %F{blue}%~ \$ %f%b'  # simplified prompt

zle_highlight=(default:bold,fg=white)
```

More information about how to use `zle_highlight` can be found in `man zshzle`.

---

Based on the linked screenshot, it looks like something is already formatting your the command input; you may want to run `print $zle_highlight` first to see its current value and modify it accordingly, or research your existing configuration for the source of the current colorization.

Comment: It turns out that the plugin zsh-syntax-highlighting also modifies this variable. Realised this after setting zle_highlight and seeing no change. Adding this line to .zshrc did the job. ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[builtin]='fg=yourColor,bold'